# Is there any proteus (runtime layout engine) version of react-native?

Tags: react-native, android-layout, backend, proteus, layout-engine

[proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus) is basically a runtime layout engine for Android developed by Indian e-commerce Flipkart.

Basically, I want to be able to control my **home screen** & **Support Screen** of the app from a backend server, so that I don't have to push every for every small change and also I don't want to use web views (we all know the limitations)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a tool exists but you should look into Firebase, specifically the remote config module. It allows you to set parameters from your backend which can then be read on your mobile app, at every launch for example. This would allow you to set custom values for any variable you might need on these screens.

You could also look into AppCenter by Microsoft. It is a service which lets you deploy app updates over the air instantly, without going through the App Store and Play Store review processes. The only downside is that you can't push updates containing native code as your app needs to be re-bundled.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am already using firebase remote config, and there isn't much I can do with it just showing some stuff or hiding. still great =P